# How to add server stats channels on discord.js

Tags: discord.js, bots, template-literals

I have a basic code for a discord bot that is only used for 1 server. The end result that I want is so that the bot displays the amount of total members, human users, bots, channels, roles, categories and emojis as a list of voice channels at the top of the server. I have made the channels and used their IDs in the following code.

```
//All Members
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871913848020545546'

    const updateMembers = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`All Members: ${guild.memberCount.toLocaleString()}`)
    }

    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateMembers(guild)
}

//Members
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871916605569892373'

    const updateMembers = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`Members: ${guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`)
    }

    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateMembers(guild)
}

//Bots
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871917535589728297'

    const updateMembers = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`Bots: ${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}`)
    }

    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateMembers(guild)
}

//Channels
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871928838412705846'

    const updateChannels = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`Channels: ${guild.channels.cache.size}`)
    }

    client.on('guildChannelAdd', (channel) => updateChannels(channel.guild))
    client.on('guildChannelRemove', (channel) => updateChannels(channel.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateChannels(guild)
    }

//Roles
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871928838412705846'

    const updateRoles = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`Roles: ${guild.roles.cache.size}`)
    }

    client.on('guildRoleAdd', (role) => updateRoles(role.guild))
    client.on('guildRoleRemove', (role) => updateRoles(role.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateRoles(guild)
    }

//Categories
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871928838412705846'

    const updateCategories = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`Categories: ${guild.categories.cache.size}`)
    }

    client.on('guildCategoryAdd', (category) => updateCategories(category.guild))
    client.on('guildCategoryRemove', (category) => updateCategories(category.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateCategories(guild)
    }

//Emojis
module.exports = client => {
    const channelId = '871928838412705846'

    const updateEmojis = guild => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.setName(`Channels: ${guild.emojis.cache.size}`)
    }

    client.on('guildEmojiAdd', (emoji) => updateEmojis(emoji.guild))
    client.on('guildEmojiRemove', (emoji) => updateEmojis(emoji.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('868192571766239262')
    updateEmojis(guild)
    }
```

The All Members section doesn't update automatically, the Members and Bots sections work, the Channels section returns the wrong amount of channels, and the Roles, Categories and Emojis sections return nothing.

Please advise

Comment: Have you enabled the privileged intent for guild member data? And for the missing categories and wrong channel count, categories are in fact channels, and are counted towards the channel count in your code. Also, many of your events are inexistent. [Consult the docs for correct names.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

Comment: How can I enable the privileged intent thing? And could you please show snippets of code for what you think should be right? Because I cannot find the exact events in the docs.

Comment: You can enable the intent from the Developer Portal. Go to your bot's application, click on Bot in the sidebar and enable "Server Members Intent" under Privileged Gateway Intents. And if you follow the link I provided above the events are listed on the right.

Comment: Alright so I have turned those features on and changed the events.

Here is my new code: https://sourceb.in/nb5Gmsoktr

Problem is that the member count does not update at all, neither of them update, and channels still shows wrong ones and the rest are undefined.

Comment: How do you call these modules? Also, how is your channel count wrong? Have you tried counting them one by one and comparing the results? It should be the same.

Comment: I have a serverstats bot that says that I have 39 channels which I checked is true, and it returns 9 instead of 39 for some reason.

I got the modules from a discord.js tutorial that I've been using ever since.